# Need help finding tangent plane to a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm doing a Calc III homework problem, and I cannot seem to figure out what the correct solution is.

$$
\text{Find the equation of the tangent plane to the surface }z = 9 y^{2} -
9 x^{2}\text{ at the point }\left( -1, 4, 135 \right). \\
z = \text{______ Note: Your answer should be an expression of }x\text{ and }y\text{; e.g. "}3x - 4y + 6\text{"}
$$

Seems simple enough.
First I move $z$ from the left side of the equation and then take partial derivatives.

$$
f(x,y,z) = -9^2+9y^2-z = 0 \\
$$
Calculate partial derivatives and plug in their respective points
$$
f_x = -18x\\
f_x(x-x_0) = -18(x+1)\\
f_y = 18y\\
f_y(y-y_0) = 18(y-16)\\
f_z = -1 \\
f_z(z-z_0) = -1 (z - 135)
$$
Which should then mean that:
$$
-18(x+1)+18(y-16)-1(z-135) = 0\\
-18x-18 + 18y - 288 - z+135 = 0\\
-18x + 18y-z-171 = 0 \\
$$
We can then move $z$ back across the axis to get the answer
$$
z = -18x+18y-171
$$

This seems like it should be correct, but webwork will not accept my result. Do I have something amis?

Comment: You want to substitute the coordinates of the point (-1,4,135) into $f_x$ and $f_y$  before writing down your equation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I don't think I understand. Do you mean into the original equation, before I take the partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, at the point $(-1,4,135)$, the normal vector $\langle f_x, f_y,-1\rangle=\langle 18, 72, -1\rangle$; so you want to use 18, 72, and -1 as the coefficients in the equation of the tangent plane (instead of -18, 18, and -1).

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Your partial derivatives are correct, now the tangent plane at $(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$ is:

$$
z=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)
$$

and you have $x_0=-1$ , $y_0=4$, so $f_x(x_0,y_0)= 18$ and $f_y(x_0,y_0)=72$