# Calculating the equation of the tangent plane to $z=f(x,y)$ at $(2,1,\ln(3))$ where $f(x,y)=\ln(\sqrt{x^2+5y^2})$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(x,y)=\ln(\sqrt{x^2+5y^2})$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$
>
> a) Calculate the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$
> and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$
>
> b) Calculate the equation of the tangent plane to $z=f(x,y)$ at
> $(2,1,\ln(3))$

**My Approach:**

I know how to do the first part, but I don't know how to find part (b).

This is my answer for part (a):

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5y^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5y^2}} \cdot2x=\frac{x}{x^2+5y^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{5y}{x^2+5y^2}$$

How do I do part b?

Comment: @NormalHuman Thank you. Is it better now? :)

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks for editing. Do you know the formula for tangent plane? It involves those partial derivatives.

Comment: @NormalHuman Really? No, Im not aware of a formula.

Comment: [It looks like this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1348610); picked from one of many questions you can see in the Related column on the right.

Comment: @NormalHuman Thank you very much :) Let me have a look.